# Next.js layout runs children logic prior to redirects

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm using the app router in Next.js 13 to redirect users to the login page when they are not logged in. I do this in the *layout.tsx* of a page folder. I effectively want to check if the user is logged in and only render/run the logic of the layout children if a redirect does not occur.

The *layout.tsx* file:

```js
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "@/components/nav-bar";
import { DecodedIdToken } from "firebase-admin/auth";
import { getUser } from "@/components/get-user";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function RecruiterLayout({
    children, // Will be a page or nested layout
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {

    const user: DecodedIdToken | null = await getUser();
    if (user === null) {
        return redirect("/auth/login");
    } else if (user.role === "recruiter" || user.role === "coordinator") {
        return redirect("/recruiter/home");
    }
    return (
        <section className="flex h-screen flex-col grow-0 overflow-y-hidden">
            <div className="flex-0 px-4 border-y"><NavBar /></div>
            <div className="flex-1 overflow-y-hidden">
                {children}
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

The child page that is getting run when the user navigates to it:

```js
import ClientComponent from "@/app/recruiter/home/components/client-component";
import getData from "@/app/api/getData";


export default async function Page() {
    // const students = await getStudents()
    const new_students = await getData({ collection_name: 'users' })
    console.log(new_students);
    return (
        <ClientComponent students={new_students} />
    )
}
```

My problem is that the layout file will properly redirect the user to the login page, but will still run the child *page.tsx* logic, meaning a database call is made on server side even if the user is not authenticated.

A similar problem has been brought up in [one of the discussion boards](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/58205) on Next's Git repository on GitHub, but has not been answered.

Is there a built-in mechanism or recommended pattern in Next.js for halting the execution of a page's rendering logic if a redirect is performed at the layout level? Or should I be handling redirect logic like this differently?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77877350/timeline) might have attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) plagiariser. Also noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78120652/applying-lookup-in-deeply-nested-array-of-objects-in-mongodb/78165002#comment137808403_78165002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your situation, using API Middleware (Edge Functions) seems to be the best approach.

Try the below in your *middleware.ts* file:

```js
// pages/recruiter/_middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getUserFromRequest } from 'path-to-your-auth-utils'; // Import your actual auth utilities

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const user = await getUserFromRequest(request); // Implement this function based on your auth system

    // Check if the user is authenticated and has the correct role
    if (!user) {
        // Redirect unauthenticated users to the login page
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', request.url));
    } else if (user.role !== 'recruiter' && user.role !== 'coordinator') {
        // Redirect authenticated users with incorrect roles
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/unauthorized', request.url)); // Change '/unauthorized' to your preferred path
    }

    // Continue with the request if the user is authenticated and authorized
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Comment: Does the API middleware get run for page routes?

Comment: @ngood97 Yes, API middleware in Next.js, also known as Edge Middleware, is executed for page requests. It operates at the network edge, handling requests before they reach Next.js pages or APIs. This feature enables pre-request actions like authentication and redirects. The scope of the middleware depends on its placement within the project's directory structure, allowing targeted application across different routes

Comment: Was the code generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have no clue, but the thought process was correct. Using middleware is pretty standard for this type of problem, I just made the stereotypical mistake of not thoroughly reading documentation.