# Applying lookup in deeply nested array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I have a query to fetch documents from a deeply nested documents having objectIds. I want to fetch some details of each prop from its objectIds. The query:

```
      const result = await this.ticketsv2Model
        .aggregate([
          {
            $match: query,
          },
          {
            $sort: {
              createdAt: -1,
            },
          },
          ...generateLookupStage('issues', 'issueId', ['_id', 'name']),
          ...generateLookupStage('subissues', 'subIssueId', ['_id', 'name']),
          ...generateLookupStage('tickettypes', 'typeId', ['_id', 'name']),
          ...generateLookupStage('statustypes', 'statusId', ['_id', 'name']),
          ...generateLookupStage('departments', 'assignedDepartment', [
            '_id',
            'name',
          ]),
          ...generateLookupStage('users', 'assignedTo', [
            '_id',
            'extension',
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
          ]),
          ...generateLookupStage('users', 'openedBy', [
            '_id',
            'extension',
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
          ]),

          {
            $unwind: '$ticketLogs',
          },
          ...generateLookupStage('users', 'ticketLogs.userId', [
            '_id',
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
            'extension',
          ]),
          ...generateLookupStage('statustypes', 'ticketLogs.statusId', [
            '_id',
            'name',
          ]),

          ...generateLookupStage(
            'departments',
            'ticketLogs.assignedDepartment',
            ['_id', 'name', 'number'],
          ),
          ...generateLookupStage('users', 'ticketLogs.assignedTo', [
            '_id',
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
            'extension',
          ]),
          {
            $group: {
              _id: '$_id',
              issueId: { $first: '$issueId' },
              subIssueId: { $first: '$subIssueId' },
              typeId: { $first: '$typeId' },
              ticketId: { $first: '$ticketId' },
              resolutionTime: { $first: '$resolutionTime' },
              clientInfo: { $first: '$clientInfo' },
              statusId: { $first: '$statusId' },
              openedBy: { $first: '$openedBy' },
              remarks: { $first: '$remarks' },
              assignedTo: { $first: '$assignedTo' },
              assignedDepartment: { $first: '$assignedDepartment' },
              ticketLogs: {
                $push: {
                  chatId: '$ticketLogs.chatId',
                  recordingId: '$ticketLogs.recordingId',
                  voiceMailRecordingId: '$ticketLogs.voiceMailRecordingId',
                  remarks: '$ticketLogs.remarks',
                  statusId: '$ticketLogs.statusId',
                  userId: '$ticketLogs.userId',
                  assignedTo: '$ticketLogs.assignedTo',
                  assignedDepartment: '$ticketLogs.assignedDepartment',
                  comments: '$ticketLogs.comments',
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $project: {
              createdAt: 1,
              issueId: 1,
              subIssueId: 1,
              typeId: 1,
              clientInfo: 1,
              statusId: 1,
              remarks: 1,
              assignedDepartment: 1,
              assignedTo: 1,
              ticketLogs: 1,
              ticketId: 1,
              openedBy: 1,
              _id: 1,
              action: {
                $switch: {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: {
                        $eq: ['$assignedTo._id', new Types.ObjectId(user)],
                      },
                      then: 'update',
                    },
                    {
                      case: {
                        $and: [
                          {
                            $in: ['$assignedDepartment._id', userDepartments],
                          },
                          { $eq: [{ $type: '$assignedTo._id' }, 'missing'] },
                        ],
                      },
                      then: 'pick',
                    },
                  ],
                  default: 'view',
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ])
        .exec();
```

The generateLookup component is a custom function to apply lookups (from, localfield & as, [props you want to fectch from the document]. My example ticket document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65b2143e5b239b78bc756a68"
  },
  "issueId": {
    "$oid": "644e940200d3bd6ab311f1fb"
  },
  "subIssueId": {
    "$oid": "644e94b100d3bd6ab311f216"
  },
  "typeId": {
    "$oid": "65828ebea1726254da22e506"
  },
  "clientInfo": {
    "clientId": "1231235645123",
    "clientEmail": "arpan@arpan.com",
    "clientPhone": "12233",
    "clientName": "Arpan Dhakal",
    "clientImage": "linkto.image",
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "65b2143e5b239b78bc756a69"
    }
  },
  "statusId": {
    "$oid": "658294ca9777467f6777802e"
  },
  "remarks": "Custom remarks here",
  "assignedDepartment": {
    "$oid": "658294a2aa8146af8fe85b50"
  },
  "ticketLogs": [
    {
      "chatId": "658294a2aa8146af8fe85b50",
      "recordingId": "658294a2aa8146af8fe85b50",
      "voiceMailRecordingId": "658294a2aa8146af8fe85b50",
      "remarks": "Ticket Created",
      "statusId": {
        "$oid": "658294f1660cac3e3acda29a"
      },
      "userId": {
        "$oid": "65af5d2e08a356fd82718d64"
      },
      "assignedTo": null,
      "assignedDepartment": {
        "$oid": "658294a2aa8146af8fe85b50"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "65b2143e5b239b78bc756a6a"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2024-01-25T07:56:46.778Z"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2024-01-25T07:56:46.778Z"
      },
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment": "hello world",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-01-26T06:21:21.429Z"
          },
          "commentedBy": {
            "$oid": "65af5d2e08a356fd82718d64"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65b34f61ec6cb747fc19f73a"
          }
        },
        {
          "comment": "hello world",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-01-26T06:30:14.002Z"
          },
          "commentedBy": {
            "$oid": "65af5d2e08a356fd82718d64"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65b35176cb2f23c9563c45f5"
          }
        },
        {
          "comment": "comment",
          "commentedBy": {
            "$oid": "644e06fc00d3bd6ab311d5fd"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65e99131c599c2d633062497"
          },
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-03-07T10:04:33.007Z"
          },
          "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2024-03-07T10:04:33.007Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ticketId": "T-55NNXUBW",
  "openedBy": {
    "$oid": "644e06fc00d3bd6ab311d5fd"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-25T07:56:46.778Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-03-07T10:04:33.007Z"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "assignedTo": {
    "$oid": "644e06fc00d3bd6ab311d5fd"
  }
}
```

Basically, my document has ticketLogs which is array of objects of ticketLogs document. Each ticketLog has comments which is array of objects of comments document. This query works for fetching user, status, department details of each ticketLogs. Now I want to fetch user details of each comments. The comments has props comment, commentedBy. I want the commentedBy to display information of the user who commented.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78120652/timeline) probably attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) plagiariser.

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can't it [be reduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?